# Как проитерироваться по локальным переменным?

Tags: c++, c++11

У меня есть 4 локальных переменных-указателя разных типов `A*, B*, C*, D*`, но которые наследуются от одного типа `A`. Надо сделать одно и то же действие-функцию `A::do_it()` над каждым объектом. Чтобы не писать одинаковый код 4 раза, хочу сделать цикл по этим объектам такого вида:

```
for (A* obj : {a, b, c, d}) {
  obj->do_it();
}
```

Какой контейнер правильно применять, чтобы работало и не было лишних копий?

Comment: может изначально сделать вектор указателей на A и не пользоваться "локальными переменными"? хотя никто не мешает их туда и так добавить

Comment: @KoVadim удобнее работать, когда это 4 обособленных объекта со своими хорошо названными именами. Только 1 общую операцию над ними надо сделать, всё остальное по своей программе

Comment: а чем вариант в вопросе не устраивает?

Comment: @Fat-Zer не компилируется, пишет, что не может дедуснуть тип `std::initializer_list<T>`; только если явно тип `std::initializer_list<A*>` написать + инклюд, то работает

Comment: @db_soul, [УМВР](https://godbolt.org/z/6E3nhqdce)... [mcve], версию компилятора и точную ошибку в студию...

Comment: @Fat-Zer действительно, похоже там сложная иерархия (это Qt классы) а не такой простой случай

Comment: ¿если работает, то в чем же проблема?

Comment: если типы переменных разные, то так или иначе придётся явно указать, какого типа должн быть список инициализации...

Comment: Ну, чтоб покороче было - `for(A* x: vector<A*>({a,b,c,d}))` устроит? :) Просто чуточку короче, чем `for(A* x: initializer_list<A*>({a,b,c,d}))`...

Comment: а чем вариант в вопросе не устраивает?

Answer (score 1):

Для QT классов не получится сделать. Надо явно писать

`for(A* x: initializer_list<A*>({a,b,c,d}))`